# Wifi in Raspberrypi makes me Crazy

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi

Suddenly the WiFi network stopped working and after that I couldnt connect with Wifi. I checked the interfaces and I found onley `eth0`. The output of iwconfig is:

```
lo no wireless extensions
eth0 no wireless extensions
```

and then i tried `ifup wlan0` and the output was :

```
ifup: interface wlan0 already configured
```

The strange thing that when I try the SD card on another Raspberry Pi the WiFi works on it but also the same result. Any help please

Comment: for Dedugging the problem i type
sudo wpa_cli

the result was 
CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=16
CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=1 ssid="***" aut_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED

Comment: Make sure you are using a good power adapter. Most WiFi problems are caused by not enough power or a really bad (cheap) power adapter that supplies tooooo much noise. Problem is... there is no easy way to identify the best power adapter. To start, you can use your PC USB if it can supply 1A (It has the cleanest power) and if WiFi still acting stupid then maybe you have defective Pi or too much WiFi noise? (bad power supply that has to much noise causes the WiFi radio waves to be generated incorrectly, causing connection problems)

Comment: You tried the SD from broken Pi into another Pi and the WiFi works on the other Pi with the broken Pi WiFi SD Card?

Comment: You have provided NO INFORMATION; are typing bizarre commands (why?) so NO ONE can possibly help.

Comment: I am here another time at first i tried sd card with Raspbian OS on one Raspberrypi and the wifi was currepted after that i get the same SD card and pluged it in another > Raspberrypi and everythinf is Good and the wifi is working perfect but in the other raspberrypi still not work @ppumkin

Comment: I am ready to provide another information onley told me what infos you want and i am ready @Milliways

Comment: I try your solution but it didnt work sorry i get the power from usb computer port put no result

Comment: OK so not a power problem :D This is going to be difficult then. Try formatting the SD card and starting from fresh. I am not a pro linux user but I am unsure what could happen when swapping SD cards from one device to another. Maybe its just a config issue then on the one Pi? Clean SD card can only proove that. Otherwise, it sounds like the Pi is damaged.

Comment: i think so also becouse i tried to format the SD card and install fresh version but also no result